# Failed to connect to separate docker container with Redis

Tags: docker, go, redis

I have redis exposed via a container:

`service_redis 0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp`

And I can even connect to it via `redis-cli` command with. But what I actually can't do, is to connect to via Go code (which also exists in a separate container, btw)

Here's how my client looks like:

```golang
opts := &redis.Options{
    Addr: addr,
    Password: pass,
    DB: db,
}


cli := redis.NewClient(opts)
fmt.Println(master.Ping().Err())
fmt.Println(slave.Get("REAL_KEY").String())
```

I've tried to put in the `addr` variable the following:

1. `0.0.0.0:6379` AND `127.0.0.1:6379`. The response was e.g.:

```
<nil>
get REAL KEY: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: connect: connection refused
```

2. `service_redis:6379` with the following response:

```
<nil>
get REAL KEY: dial tcp: lookup service_redis on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
```

How can I solve the problem and what did I wrong?

Comment: I am assuming this is Kubernetes, are you connecting from the same namespace?

Comment: Nope. Honestly, I have no access to k8s itself, but my teammate says, that redis is inside one. But Currently, my container w/ go is not. So it's not the same pod

Comment: Can you tell me in what namespace redis is? You need to construct the url using the namespace if it's not the same one you are connecting from

Comment: Seems like to be a good hint. Am I able to get a namespace with no access to k8s itself?

Comment: Since you can connect using `redis-cli`, your Redis is running locally on `127.0.0.1:6379`. But if you are using Docker, you should use Docker network. In case you are using docker-compose, you can connect using network name: something like `redis:6379`. In case of k8s you should use k8s DNS convention - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
web:
    build: .
    working_dir: /go/src
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/go/src
    links:
     - db
db:
    image: redis
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
```

Its creating a link between you containers so they can communicate to eachother.
If you don't want to use `docker-compose.yaml` then you could use the `--link` flag when building your image

Answer (score 0):

Are you using docker-compose?
Specify the addr/host as the container reference

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      REDIS_HOST: redis:6379

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
```

You can now access this in your app:

```golang
addr := os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST")

// storage/redis.go
opts := &redis.Options{
    Addr: addr,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Kubernetes would make the discovery simple. I have written a redis replication and fail over k8s config with read write in go to redis. [check https://github.com/kubesure/premium](https://github.com/kubesure/premium)